# Jquery to make recursive divs- possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not sure how to do this but I'm trying to make divs behave like columns that stretch across the screen evenly (this is done/easy) and then make sub columns.  Here's what I have:
JS:

```
$(function() {
    cols = $('.column');
    parent_width = cols.parent().width();
    col_fluff = parseInt(cols.css('padding-left'))+parseInt(cols.css('padding-right'))+parseInt(cols.css('margin-left'))+parseInt(cols.css('margin-right'));
    col_width = (Math.floor(parent_width/cols.size()-col_fluff));

    cols.each(function(){
        $(this).width(col_width);
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#container{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin-top:50px;
}
.column{
    float:left;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    margin-right:20px;
    outline:#000 solid 2px;
    width:20%;
}
.clear{
    clear:both;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="column">
    This is some text : This is some text : This is some text : This is some text :This is some text : This is some text :This is some text : This is some text :This is some text : This is some text :This is some text : This is some text :This is some text : This is some text :This is some text : This is some text :This is some text : This is some text 
    </div>
    <div class="column">
    This is some text : This is some text : This is some text : This is some text :This is some text : This is some text :This is some text : This is some text :This is some text : This is some text :This is some text : This is some text :This is some text : This is some text :This is some text : This is some text :This is some text : This is some text 
    </div>
    <div class="clear">clear</div>
</div><!-- end container -->
```

This works fine until you try a inserting an inner column:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="column">
    This is some text : This is some text : This is some text : This is some text :This is some text : This is some text :This is some text : This is some text :This is some text : This is some text :This is some text : This is some text :This is some text : This is some text :This is some text : This is some text :This is some text : This is some text 
        <div class="column">
            inner column
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            inner column
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
    This is some text : This is some text : This is some text : This is some text :This is some text : This is some text :This is some text : This is some text :This is some text : This is some text :This is some text : This is some text :This is some text : This is some text :This is some text : This is some text :This is some text : This is some text 
    </div>
    <div class="clear">clear</div>
</div><!-- end container -->
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How would the widths be decided?  Always even spacing at every depth?

Comment: @Orbling, good question.  I have jquery making a width by percentage so it's "even" relatively to the parent and the number of siblings and element has.

Comment: Aye, that would be the only way to handle it automatically.  Unless there were some hints at desired ratios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can arrange column width by level from outer to inner columns:

Define a function that takes the outermost parent element containing `$('.column')` elements and arrage it's direct children, then apply the same function to each `$('.column')` children (as a parent now, to arrange its children) recursively...

```
$(function(){
    function Arrange(colsParent){

        cols = colsParent.children('.column');
        parent_width = cols.parent().width();
        col_fluff = parseInt(cols.css('padding-left'))
                   +parseInt(cols.css('padding-right'))
                   +parseInt(cols.css('margin-left'))
                   +parseInt(cols.css('margin-right'));
        col_width = (Math.floor(parent_width/cols.size()-col_fluff));

        cols.each(function(){
            $(this).width(col_width);
        });


        cols.each(function(){
            Arrange($(this));
        });
    }

    level1ColsParent = $('.column').first().parent();

    Arrange(level1ColsParent);
});
```

Comment: Oh that does the trick!  @manji, how might I iterate over the first level parents?    I tried something like this to no avail: level1ColsParent = $('div[id^=container]');

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to use `display:table-row`, `display:table-cell` to make things a lot more easier. It will automatically arrange your columns and subcolumns in equal width tabular form.

Comment: IE only supports those settings as of IE8, a surprisingly large section of the market are still below that.  I know people, including myself, are forcibly pushing IE6 out now, but IE7 is still generally to be catered for.

Comment: Yeah good calls but IE7 will surely sneak it's ugly head into this so you have to make a Faustian concession sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you will have a problem because of the fact that with

```
cols = $('.column');
```

you will always get ALL the divs (and any other elements) with that class of the entire document, but what you really want to get is only the children divs/elements of a particular element.

You might try adding a parameter that is the parent element for the columns you will resize per function call.

To get the columns of a particular parent element, you could use the children function.

So pretending that you pass in the parent element, of which you plan to resize all the divs that are children of this parent, you could use this line:

```
cols = $(parent_element).children('.column');
```

Also, to make the function recursive you will have to call itself from within the cols.each. Pass in the children so that they will be used as the parent in the next level of calls. I will assume that you can give the function the name of resize_columns_recursive.

Finally the end result would look something like:

```
function resize_columns_recursive(parent_element){

  var cols = parent_element.children('.column');
  var col_fluff = parseInt(cols.css('padding-left'))+parseInt(cols.css('padding-right'))+parseInt(cols.css('margin-left'))+parseInt(cols.css('margin-right'));
  var col_width = (Math.floor(parent_element.width()/cols.size()-col_fluff));

  cols.each(function(){
    $(this).width(col_width);
    resize_columns_recursive(this);
  });    

}
```

EDIT: I made the local vars local with the var declaration. This seems to be working on jsfiddle (see comments).

Comment: This is very close to working but for something reason, the recursive part makes only the first children work: http://jsfiddle.net/DPpQQ/

Comment: Nice catch! The vars in the function need to be local instead of global. I added the "var" declaration where appropriate. I also updated on [http://jsfiddle.net/DPpQQ/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/DPpQQ/1).